# How to reuse slide up menu class in any view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, protocols

I am trying to create a slide up menu, completely defined in a custom class named OldMenu.

It would show every time a user tap a UIBarButtonItem, that is also defined in that class.

So the button, the menu, and the menu animation to show the menu are all defined in this custom class.

For now, I can just access the button from an other class but it doesn't seem to trigger the animation to show the menu.

Any one knows why this code isn't working?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let oldMenu = OldMenu()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [oldMenu.MenuButton]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

class OldMenu: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView: UITableView {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        return tableView
    }
    
    var transparentView = UIView()
    
    let height: CGFloat = 250
    
    var MenuButton: UIBarButtonItem {
        let btn = UIBarButtonItem()
        btn.title = "Menu"
        btn.target = self
        btn.action = #selector(onClickMenu)
        return btn
    }
}

extension OldMenu {
    
    @objc func onClickMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
        transparentView.frame = window?.bounds ?? .zero
        window?.addSubview(transparentView)
        
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height, width: screenSize.width, height: height)
        window?.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onClickTransparentView))
        transparentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        transparentView.alpha = 0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transparentView.alpha = 0.5
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height - self.height, width: screenSize.width, height: self.height)
        }, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    @objc func onClickTransparentView() {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transparentView.alpha = 0
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height, width: screenSize.width, height: self.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension OldMenu {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var oldMenu: OldMenu!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
    
       oldMenu = OldMenu(controller: self)
       navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = oldMenu.MenuButton
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}

extension ViewController: MenuDelegate {


   func tableRowDidSelect(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
   }
}
```

**OldMenu**

```
class OldMenu: NSObject {
    
    var presenter: UIViewController?
    
    var menuController = MenuViewController()

    var MenuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    init(controller: UIViewController?) {
        super.init()
        presenter = controller
        MenuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onClickMenu))
    }
    
    @objc func onClickMenu() {
        menuController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        menuController.transitioningDelegate = self
        menuController.delegate = presenter as! MenuDelegate
        presenter?.present(menuController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension OldMenu: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        PresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
    }
    
}
```

**MenuViewController**

Configure your tableView in MenuViewController, and use delegates to communicate back to the main view

```
protocol MenuDelegate {
    func tableRowDidSelect(_ indexPath: IndexPath)
}

// Configure your tableView in MenuViewController
// Use delegates to communicate back to main view
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: MenuDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
    }
}
```

**PresentationController**

You can reuse PresentationController to present view controllers in half screen.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PresentationController: UIPresentationController {

  let blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!
  var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
  
  override init(presentedViewController: UIViewController, presenting presentingViewController: UIViewController?) {
      let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
      blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
      super.init(presentedViewController: presentedViewController, presenting: presentingViewController)
      tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissController))
      blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
      self.blurEffectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      self.blurEffectView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
  }
  
  override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {

      // Set your presentation height
      let presentHeight: CGFloat = 300
      
      return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.containerView!.frame.height - presentHeight),
             size: CGSize(width: self.containerView!.frame.width, height: presentHeight))
  }

  override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
      self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
      self.containerView?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
      self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
          self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0.5
      }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in })
  }
  
  override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
      self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
          self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
      }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
          self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
      })
  }
  
  override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {
      super.containerViewWillLayoutSubviews()
      
      // set your corner radius
    presentedView!.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 18)
  }

  override func containerViewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.containerViewDidLayoutSubviews()
      presentedView?.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
      blurEffectView.frame = containerView!.bounds
  }

  @objc func dismissController(){
      self.presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

extension UIView {
  func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
      let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners,
                              cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
      let mask = CAShapeLayer()
      mask.path = path.cgPath
      layer.mask = mask
  }
}
```

## Result

[image]